# Touch Events for UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, event-handling, hittest, touch-event

I have a `UIView` overlaying a subclassed `UITableview`. The problem is that ,I cant get the tableview to scroll. I have tried overriding `touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved`,`touchesEnded`. I then tried to override hittest but that seemed to have no affect.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"SMTable.touches began %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"SMTable.touches moved %@ for :%p",NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint),touch.view);
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"SMTable.touches ended %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (UIView*) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //NSLog(@"SMTable.hitTest %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: overlayView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `UIView` is above your `UITableView`, then all touch events will land in that `UIView` and your `UITableView` will not scroll. You need to disable interaction for your top most `UIView˜

Comment: I dont think that will work because I need to intercept touch events for the overlayView too

Answer (score 0):

When you need to create a specialized `UITableView` you are almost always better off using a `UIViewController` that contains a `UITableView` rather than mucking around in the `UITableView` hierarchy if at all possible. Apple are doing quite a bit of stuff in the tableview hierarchy which makes adding your own custom views to it often go awry. So, the short answer is : avoid inserting your own views into the tableView hierarchy.

In fact, I almost never use a `UITableViewController` subclass anymore. I always find myself needing to customize the view controller in a way that isn't easily supported from a `UITableViewController`-- such as creating a view to overlay the tableView as you are doing. Instead, create your controller like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView

@end
```

If you are using Interface Builder, drop your tableView into the view controller's view and set the delegate and datasource to the view's owner. Or you can do the same thing in code via the `viewDidLoad` method. In either case, at this point you can **treat the view controller exactly as if it were a UITableViewController with the added benefit of being able to do things like inserting views into `self.view` without things going horribly awry.**